# Focus issue when text inputs are used in a template repeat

Tags: dart, dart-webui

Input texts are inserted in the DOM using an iterable repeat like the following:

HTML:

```html
<template repeat="value in listValue">
  <input type="text" bind-value="listValue[$index]">
</template>
```

Dart:

```dart
List listValue = toObservable(["value one", "value two"]);
```

There is a problem with the focus: when a letter is typed in any of the input field, the DOM is redisplayed and the focus is lost. This is due to [focus bug](https://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui/issues/537)

How could I have this working?

Answer (score 0):

The focus problem is a result that WebUI currently considers changes to individual entries in a list as a general change to the list itself, so it re-renders the entire template-repeat on every edit. You can get the behavior you want by adding one level of indirection. The idea here is to make it easier to distinguish changes to values from changes to the list.

For instance, instead of having list of string values, make it a list of observable references to string values, as follows:

html:

```
<template repeat="value in listValue">
  <input type="text" bind-value="value.value">
</template>
```

dart:

```
import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';
List listValue = toObservable([]);

void main() {
  listValue.add(new ObservableReference("value one"));
  listValue.add(new ObservableReference("value two"));
}
```